# Suppress 2-letter ligature when 3-letter ligature would apply

Tags: fonts, automation, ligatures

Automatic handling of ligatures in TeX seems [notoriously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/ligature-suppression-with-proper-hyphenation-and-comprehensive-word-list) [difficult](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28437/can-one-more-or-less-automatically-suppress-ligatures-for-certain-words) but I was wondering whether in a font that has an `ff` and an `fl` ligature but no `ffl` one, it was possible to suppress the usage of any ligatures for instances of "ffl" in the text. Example follows:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{uop}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Muffling affluent waffles baffles sniffling Mifflin.

Muf{}f{}ling af{}f{}luent waf{}f{}les baf{}f{}les snif{}f{}ling Mif{}f{}lin.
\end{document}
```

[image: many ffl words with and without ligature]

As it stands now, the "ffl" words seem unbalanced *because* of the inappropriate ligature they contain (the "fl" is closer together than the "ff"). Manually fixing every word is not a solution I'd look forward to.

Comment: Run tftopl on the tfm file, delete the ligatures that you don't want then run pltotf to make a (locally modified) tfm.

Comment: Does this answer of mine help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106446/4427

Comment: However, you need to define new ligatures if this must be context sensitive.

Comment: @egreg Your answer should help but when I generate a `uopb8r.pl`, neither `146` (octal code for `f`) nor `257` (`ﬂ`) are anywhere to be found. Which is odd because the above example clearly shows that some ligaturing involving the letter "f" is going on and an "ﬀ" ligature doesn't seem to be part of the font according to fontforge.

Comment: You should do `tftopl uopr7t`, not using the “raw” font.

Comment: On a related note, this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3279/13450 by @GeoffreyJones seems to indicate that -- ligature or not -- this odd splitting of the `f` from the `ﬂ` might be a feature as in "intended by the font designer". Who were I to argue with Mr Zapf in that case.

Comment: @egreg Ok, did that but the result is much the same. Still no `146` or `257`.

Comment: @Christian Where can the font files be found?

Comment: @egreg They used to be in TeXLive but these days you'll have to `getnonfreefonts-sys classico` http://micahyi.blogspot.de/2012/05/install-non-free-font-for-latex-tex.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font has only the `fi` and `fl` ligatures, which are actually unnecessary; the `ff`, `ffi` and `ffl` ligatures are obtained in the virtual font by putting together two `f`'s or an `f` with `fi` or `fl` respectively; here is the relevant part for `ffl`:

### `tftopl uopr7t`

First of all, let's look at `f`:

```
(CHARACTER C f
   (CHARWD R 0.276)
   (CHARHT R 0.745999)
   (CHARDP R 0.0055)
   (COMMENT
      (LIG C i O 14)
      (LIG C f O 13)
      (LIG C l O 15)
   [...]
```

So `ff` is octal 13:

```
(CHARACTER O 13
   (CHARWD R 0.573)
   (CHARHT R 0.745999)
   (CHARDP R 0.0055)
   (COMMENT
      (LIG C i O 16)
      (LIG C l O 17)
   [...]
```

Thus `ffl` is at position octal 17.

### `vptovf uopr7t`

```
[...]
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
[...]
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME uopr8r)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 35406442446)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

This says what font the glyphs are taken from. Let's see octal 17:

```
(CHARACTER O 17
   (CHARWD R 0.834)
   (CHARHT R 0.745999)
   (CHARDP R 0.0055)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C v R -0.019)
      (KRN C y R -0.021)
      )
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C f)
      (MOVERIGHT R 0.021)
      (SETCHAR O 3)
      )
   )
```

This says that the character `f` is typeset, there is a kern of 0.21pt (the design size is 10pt) and then character octal 3 is used; in the raw font, the `fl` ligature is there.

The same kerning is applied when building the `ff` ligature. However, this results in the two `f`'s being farther apart than they would be without the ligature, as your picture shows.

It seems to have been done not too carefully; my suggestion is to disable all `f` ligatures.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=*,family=uop}

\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{uop}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent % show that ligatures are not disabled altogether
Muffling affluent waffles\\
baffles sniffling Mifflin.

\sffamily
\noindent % but only for the classico font
Muffling affluent waffles\\
baffles sniffling Mifflin.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX, you could employ the [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package -- full disclosure: I'm the author of this package :-) -- to easily disable the `ff` and `fl` ligatures for words that include the `ffl` triple. (Words that contain just `ff` or `fl` will see the corresponding ligatures preserved.) Ligature suppression can be switched off and back on via the package's `\selnoligoff` and `\selnoligon` macros.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman} 
\usepackage{selnolig} % for this example, load the package *without* a language option
\nolig{ffl}{f|f|l} % suppress both ff and fl ligatures in words that contain ffl
\begin{document}
``ffl'' ligature disabled:

Muffling affluent waffles baffles sniffling Mifflin

\medskip
but ``ff'' and ``fl'' ligatures still work:

off fly

\selnoligoff % turn off selnolig's work, i.e., re-enable ffl ligature
\bigskip
``ffl'' ligature can be re-enabled:

Muffling affluent waffles baffles sniffling Mifflin
\end{document}
```

Aside: I've used the "standard" Latin Modern fonts in this example since I don't have the "Classico" fonts on my system. Assuming there exists a package named, say, "classico.sty", that loads the Classico font family, you should be able to execute the macros (after loading `fontspec`) `\usepackage{classico}` and `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` to use this Classico font under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It's a perfect solution but unfortunately I at some point gave up on LuaLaTeX for this particular document because it inflicted terrible mayhem on my math. More precisely, `unicode-math` did IIRC.

Comment: @Christian - Sorry to learn about your troubles with math support under LuaLaTeX. How long ago was this? The `unicode-math` has been getting loads better of late. By the way, I looked up information about the Classico font; it seems to be based on Zapf's Optima font. Now, Optima provides ligatures only for fi and fl, but not for ff, let alone for ffi and ffl. If that applies to Classico as well, there's no need to try to suppress the non-existent ff ligature; you can concentrate on the easier task of suppressing the fl ligature in words that contain ffl.

Comment: Oh it's been a while. I just tried to compile my document with the TeXLive 2013 lualatex though and it doesn't even compile anymore :/ Some problem in `amsthm` apparently. Anyway, yes URW Classico is the free clone of Optima but Zapf was somehow still personally involved (that's why I said I didn't want to argue with him earlier ;) and it inherits its lack of `ﬀ`. I've been fighting the urge to just shell out a couple hundred bucks and buy Optima Nova for years but that would rely on LuaLaTeX working flawlessly with my document.

Comment: @Christian - You may want to consider posting an MWE that asks how to go about fixing whatever is keeping your math stuff from compiling under LuaLaTeX/unicode-math. Somebody may be able to come up with a solution. :-)

Comment: I should probably do that ;) With the amount of packages I'm using, a MWE can take anything between 2 minutes and an hour to make ... okok, I'll get to it. Here's to hoping for a quick one.

Comment: Had to go to bed after 3h but I had gotten it to work without help ... "work" as in "it compiles without errors". But apparently the selection of unicode math fonts is still very limited and there's nothing that I can see going well together with Optima (as the type 1 Iwona Math does). I remember now that actually the problem last time that screwed up my math was using LuaLaTeX *without* `unicode-math` so I need it but at the same time there just aren't many options outside the serif realm :/

Comment: @Christian - Glad to read your compilation-related problems got resolved. I remember reading once -- I can't remember where -- that Optima is not so much a sans-serif font but a "serifless Roman" font. If Optima and Palatino are juxtaposed, they are indeed amazingly similar in proportions. (Exception: Italic Optima is noticeably more slanted that Italic Palatino.) Is Palatino (Full Math Font: TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular) an acceptable text/math font for your purposes? (Warning: the displaystyle-size integral symbol provided by TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular is much too small, IMNSHO.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15214055#15214055)